# How do I perform automated browser testing with Node.js and two-way ssl?

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests, phantomjs, zombie.js

I'm looking for a module to let me do browser testing on a site that requires two-way SSL. I've successfully tested the API for the site using the client certs provided to me, so I know the certs are good.

I've tried using:

Phatom.js - apparently it doesn't support client certs.

Selenium with the WD module - I don't see how I can pass in the certificate, and for some reason the Firefox instance that starts up doesn't use the certificate I've already stored in Firefox.

Zombie.js - I tried passing in the client certs as options, but kept getting a bad cert error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After a quick search I found this article which explains how to do it with Selenium WebDriver. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889085/automating-ssl-client-side-certificates-in-firefox-and-selenium-testing

The key with selenium is you have to prepare the profile so Firefox knows what configuration to start in. Otherwise it just opens a browser with a default profile loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, it got me on the right track.  I ended up creating a Firefox Profile via the command line:
/usr/bin/firefox -P

I created a new profile named Selenium, and started Firefox with that profile. I then imported my cert. Under Firefox Preferences -> Advanced -> Encryption, make sure you select "Select One Automatically" under the Certificates question, otherwise you'll get a popup.

Then, when I want to start the selenium server:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=Selenium