# SSL Certs acceptance using AutoIT

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, autoit

Is it possible to accept SSL Certificates in Chrome/Firefox using AutoIT tool?

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I strongly assume there is a better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @FlyingFoX I want to automate the ssl certificates for my selenium testing. What solution would you suggest?

Comment: I recommend you have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10889085/783912 It should at least help you with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. You have 3 options depending on what you want to do. They are:

1. Use the [FF.au3](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/) and the [Chrome.au3](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/) UDFs plus other AutoIt automations. (Hard)
2. Use [iUIAutomation](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/?page=1) plus other AutoIt automations. (A little less hard)
3. If you just need to get some certificate info you can use this [script](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/82588-ssl-certificate-information/?do=findComment&comment=1228974). (pretty easy)

If you go with option 3 you will need to download this [UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/77503-wininetau3-ftphttphttpsgopher/) and update the WinINetConstants.Au3 file on line 5 from:

```
  Global Const $AU3_UNICODE = Number($AU3_VERSION[2] & "." & $AU3_VERSION[3]) >= 2.13 Or @AutoItUnicode
```

To

```
  Global Const $AU3_UNICODE = Number($AU3_VERSION[2] & "." & $AU3_VERSION[3]) >= 2.13 Or @AutoItVersion
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using option 3, I have modified the script. How do I run the script with my selenium code. It will be great if you can elaborate on this. P.S I'm a newbie at AutoIT.